# insertAdjacentElement is not adding or appending the element in the target element

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, dom-manipulation

I created a function to create `div`

```js
function createDivElement(className: string): HTMLDivElement {
    const divElement = document.createElement('div')
    divElement.className = className

    return divElement
}
```

after that I created another function which returns **elements** or **structure** of `Tooltip` I am making

```js
function generateTooltip() {
    const TooltipParent = createDivElement(`tooltip-parent-${randomString(8)}`)
    const Tooltip = createDivElement(`tooltip-${randomString(8)}`)
    const TooltipArrow = createDivElement(`tooltip-arrow-${randomString(8)}`)
    const TooltipContent = createDivElement(`tooltip-content-${randomString(8)}`)

    return { TooltipParent, Tooltip, TooltipArrow, TooltipContent }
}
```

and Finally I made a function that creates tooltip

```js
const Tooltip = function (props: Props) {
    'use strict'
    
    // rest of the code
    generateTooltip().Tooltip.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', generateTooltip().TooltipArrow)
    generateTooltip().Tooltip.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', generateTooltip().TooltipContent)
    generateTooltip().TooltipParent.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', generateTooltip().Tooltip)
     
    // appending on the body
    document.body.appendChild(generateTooltip().TooltipParent)
}
```

Now in `DOM` the last line of the function **i.e** appending `.tooltip-parent` div on the body is working rest of the code isn't working which means the elements above this line is not appending in the target element.

**As you can see only the element which I am appending on body is rendering in the DOM**

[image: FOR REFERENCE OR IDEA]

Comment: Where is `tooltip-parrent-zd8ptq` appended to the DOM?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I deleted that code of line by mistake wait let me edit my question! Thanks 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `generateTooltip()` you generate a new set of elements. For example, calling `generateTooltip().TooltipParent` twice will give you two different `TooltipParent` divs. So no element is referenced and appended correctly.

The solution lies in calling `generateTooltip()` only once, and use all the elements from that single call to build your structure.

```
const TooltipElement = function (props: Props) {
  const { 
    TooltipParent, 
    Tooltip, 
    TooltipArrow, 
    TooltipContent 
  } = generateTooltip();

  Tooltip.append(TooltipArrow, TooltipContent);
  TooltipParent.append(Tooltip);
  document.body.append(TooltipParent);
}
```

I rename `Tooltip` to `TooltipElement` to avoid duplicate names, as you already have `Tooltip` element inside the function.

You can still use `insertAdjacentElement` instead of `append`, but I didn't see a real advantage of use the former over the latter.

Comment: It Worked!  Thanks!!